# How to Frame,format my own packet within IP/UDP packet in C or objective C?

Tags: objective-c, c, sockets, udp

I have to communicate with a device which listens on a port for all incoming IP/UDP connection , Ethernet frame carries ip/udp packet which in turn have to carry my own packet say own packet, which is to be like following

```
|    first field              |   second field   |  third field  | fourth field |
|2byte message sequence number|1byte message type| Reserved field| Message Data |
```

how do i create my custom packet with these as my packet data?

Comment: I tried the following library to frame and send UDP packets [link]http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/source/browse/RunLoop/AsyncUdpSocket.m?r=ad134b4a2053251f0978b34f91f529b56bb73f62

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a new socket, in datagram mode.
2. Format your content into a buffer.
3. Write the buffer to the socket.

Comment: Hi Friend, Thanks for the answer i will try to this, i have another question, How to perform a AES encryption to the Message Data field?